# How to append content to wxHtmlWindow?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxhtmlwindow

I know SetPage() sets the content of wxHtmlWindow.  In my application, I will be appending more content frequently in a fashion similar to a log file, so I'd like to avoid calling SetPage() repeatedly to avoid unnecessary CPU cycles being wasted on parsing the same content over and over and keep the display from flickering too much.

I thought about using wxHtmlListBox but decided I didn't really like that solution because users won't be able to select/copy small portions of text.

Example code of appending new content to the 'body' tag would be appreciated.  I'm also open to other solutions if someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you against using AppendToPage? http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.html.HtmlWindow-class.html#AppendToPage

Comment: I somehow completely missed that function.